# Django api performance improvement

Tags: python, sql-server, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django API which is fetching records( on an avg 30000 records) from MSSQL database using stored procedures.
This API is consumed in an Angular4 web app which is used for downloading in excel format.
It is taking an average of 10 seconds for the procedure to execute and approximately 47 seconds for API to fetch it.

Let me know the areas where performance can be improved.

Comment: Please show us the queries you are doing. You can use Django-debug-toolbar to check why your queries taking so long. my suggestion would be to use `prefetch_related` etc. you are probably doing a lot of double queries.

Comment: First: profile. Until you do so, you don't know where the bottlenecks really are.